# Regular expression match "?" x times

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I want to match the symbol "!" only the first *x* times. I looked in a regular expression cheat sheet but could not find a relevant example.

My current regular expression:

```
[!]{1}
```

For example, if I want to match the first three "!" symbols and replace with an empty string:

Input: `"!!dd!!dd!!"`

Output: `"dd!dd!!"`

Comment: You kinda need to mention what technology you are using. If you were using sed it would look something like "s/^([^!]*)!([^!]*)!([^!]*)!(.*)$/\1\2\3\4/". The "([^!]*)" means to capture all non-"!" set of chars.

Comment: Your problem may be more easily solvable without regex, i.e., with a simple parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Capture pattern:

```
[!]([^!]*?)[!]([^!]*?)[!]([^!]*?)(.*)
```

Raplacement pattern:

```
$1$2$3$4
```

Basicaly, it says

- `[!]` Capture the `!`
- `([^!]*?)` Capture everything up to the next character, excluding the `!`

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/QugVGY/1)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `{3}` for exactly 3 times, `{3,5}` for between 3 to 5 times, and `{2,}` for anything more than 2 times.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Look at the example which the OP wants to happen